# How to allow filtering of plain-text into HTML tags in NodeJS and PUG?

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, pug

I have a web application in NodeJS and PUG/Jade. I want to separate the logic of the application, controlled by a developer, from the textual content, controlled by a marketing person and translators, while keeping all the source code integrated. (I asked about ways for this separation [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129177/how-to-integrate-a-nodejs-we-application-with-a-content-management-system) and got no answers as of this writing).

For English, I use a JSON object `en.json` with:

```
{
  "404": {
    "notFound": "Page not found"
  }
}
```

the controller loads it with:

```js
let localText = require('./en.json');
res.status(404).render('404', {
  text: localText
});
```

and the view renders it with:

```
h1 #{text['404'].notFound}
```

I would like to include links in the JSON object, such as:

```
{
  "404": {
    "notFound": "Page not found. Go to <a href=\"www.twitter.com\">Twitter</a>, maybe?"
  }
}
```

NodeJS renders the page with the source code and not the link. I've fixed it temporarily by splitting into three:

```
{
  "404": {
    "notFound1": "Page not found. Go to",
    "notFound2": "Twitter",
    "notFound3": ", maybe?"
  }
}
```

and the view:

```
h1 #{text['404'].notFound1} #[a(href="www.twitter.com") #{text['404'].notFound2}] #{text['404'.notFound3}
```

And it has now become a pain to maintain.

I understand [from this page](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html) that I could create a filter to pre-process all links, e.g.:

```js
options.filters = {
  'my-own-filter': function (text) {
    text = text.replace("Twitter", "<a href=\"www.twitter.com\">Twitter</a>")
    /* all other replacements */
    return text;
  }
};
```

I couldn't find how to pass such filter options to the web application, whose only PUG line is `app.set('view engine', 'pug');`.

How can I pre-process a plain-text with NodeJS and Jade to populate links and display them nicely to the browser user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) syntax (`!{variable}`) instead of the regular string interpolation syntax (`#{variable}`) to get the HTML to render correctly.

In your case:

```
h1 !{text['404'].notFound}
```

But keep in mind this word of warning from the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped):

> **Caution**
>
> Keep in mind that buffering unescaped content into your templates can be mighty risky if that content comes fresh from your users. Never trust user input!

Comment: Yes, that works. I have split the question and made the part about the markdown its [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563658/filtering-markdown-content-for-rendering-in-jade).